# How to install Python 3.6?

Tags: debian, software-installation, python

I'd like to install the latest Python, which is 3.6 at the time of this post. However, the repository is saying that Python 3.4.2 is the newest version.

I've tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3

python3 is already the newest version.

$ python -V

Python 3.4.2
```

To upgrade to Python 3.6 on my Windows workstation, I simply downloaded an exe, clicked "next" a few times, and it's done. What's the proper and officially accepted procedure to install Python 3.6 on Debian Jessie?

Comment: The default Debian repositories contains software packages specifically compiled for a certain Debian version. Except for security updates (preferably just the fewest changes needed to fix a security hole) new versions of most software may not be available until the next major release to avoid potential instability.

Comment: @phk In that case, wouldn't it be prudent to adopt a behavior similar to pip, i.e. default to 3.4.2 when a version isn't specified, and allow the user to explicitly request 3.6 with a flag? Just an idea :)

Comment: This would mean that the Debian folks would have to maintain all these Python versions for every supported Debian version. Sure, it could be automated but it would be still a lot. Also, the power users who want newer versions could just as well use custom repositories. Sometimes ,the software authors themselves are maintaining them for Debian and other popular Linux distributions, e.g. in the case of [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

Comment: Python 3.6 (though `rc1`) just arrived in Debian experimental. It's probably possible to backport it to Jessie, possibly with a little tweaking.

Comment: Update. This finished building successfully for me on Debian stable (jessie). However, that doesn't mean it will install successfully and *not* cause problems. A reasonable next step would be to test it on a test VM of stable. Does anyone care?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Editorial note:
**Warning**: this answer shows how to install Python from future releases of Debian. This **will result in a system which mixes Debian releases**, and will affect more than Python — in most cases, applying these instructions will pull in newer libraries too. The resulting setup won’t benefit from security updates with the same speed as might be expected, for packages which are updated. This is known as [a FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian).

Consider the other answers to this question instead, in particular [this one showing how to build from source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332658/86440), and [this one showing how to use virtual environments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350985/86440).

---

Debian does not have Python 3.6 in its repositories, but testing has it.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
# add
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian testing main
$ echo 'APT::Default-Release "stable";' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00local
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get -t testing install python3.6
$ python3.6 -V
```

You asked for:

> the proper and officially accepted procedure

but I must point it out that this is not official solution because it uses testing repositories.

Comment: Don't try this - it will take you ages to undo

Comment: Is this still as risky to do as suggested in August (or Dec) 2017? It's not clear anymore after @cas edited and made his comment. Can someone follow up?

Comment: As of 9/15/2018 it is still risky: I tried this on a Raspberry Pi with Debian stretch and ran into segmentation faults after the Python 3.6 upgrade from testing pulled in an updated libc6 and libc6-dev.

Comment: April 2019, still a "Bad Idea®©™", I did that yesterday, I should have been afraid of the long list of packages that would be removed, the system was in shambles, after reboot I didn't have X anymore, I didn't try to fix that and I installed Ubuntu.

Comment: Please delete this dangerous answer omg

Comment: @Brian_Peterson The approach described will always be a bad idea; see GAD3R's answer for the proper way to update an alternative python, by compiling the latest from source.

Comment: This is a totally dangerous answer and should be removed.

Answer (score 194):

You can install `Python-3.6` on Debian 8 as follows:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.9/Python-3.6.9.tgz
tar xvf Python-3.6.9.tgz
cd Python-3.6.9
./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared
make -j8
sudo make altinstall
python3.6
```

It is recommended to use `make altinstall` according to [the official website](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html#building-python).

If you want `pip` to be included, you need to add `--with-ensurepip=install` to your configure call. For more details see `./configure --help`.

> Warning: `make install` can overwrite or masquerade the python binary. `make altinstall` is therefore recommended instead of `make install` since it only installs `exec_prefix/bin/pythonversion`.

Some packages need to be installed to avoid some known problems, see: [**Common build problems**](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems)(updated)

> Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev \
libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev \
xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev
```

> Alternative of libreadline-dev:

```
sudo apt install libedit-dev
```

> Fedora/CentOS/RHEL(aws ec2):

```
sudo yum install zlib-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel readline-devel sqlite sqlite-devel \
openssl-devel xz xz-devel libffi-devel
```

> Alternative of openssl-devel:

```
sudo yum install compat-openssl10-devel --allowerasing
```

**Update**

You can download the latest `python-x.y.z.tar.gz` from [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/).

To set a default python version and easily switch between them , you need to update your `update-alternatives` with the multiple python version.

Let's say you have installed the `python3.7` on debian stretch , use the command `whereis python` to locate the binary (`*/bin/python`). e,g:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python3.5
```

Add the python versions:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/local/bin/python3.7 50
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 40
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 30
```

The `python3.7` with the `50` priority is now your default python , the `python -V` will print:

```
Python 3.7.0b2
```

To switch between them, use:

```
update-alternatives --config python
```

Sample output:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/local/bin/python3.7   50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2.7         40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.5         30        manual mode
  3            /usr/local/bin/python3.7   50        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Comment: Don't debian guys recommend `checkinstall`? Otherwise, it would be wise to install it to `/usr/local` or `/opt`.

Comment: According to `./configure --help` Python 3.6 installs to `/usr/local` per default.

Comment: and if i want to install it to `/usr` so that it overrides the python3 default?

Comment: I've tried this twice, and both times running python3.6 gives: `*** Error in `/usr/local/bin/python3.6': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f7599c5b0a0 ***` Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: @OlivierPons this kind of question can be found with a single internet search. Use just `make install` and it will do. Most of OS need to stick to Python2 because system, so we use `altinstall` to have both versions.

Comment: @erm3nda I ask questions only when I did not find something working on google :) And you're right: `altinstall` did the trick. On the contrary, this was the only working solution to be able to install it and do what I want...

Comment: @OlivierPons for the sake of your question, you could even run `.configure --prefix /usr/local/your-special-python-path`, and you may add manually the symlink named python3 to /usr/local/bin pointing to that dir, but altinstall is easier. yw.

Comment: Having trouble with this answer (e.g., SSL module not available or zlib missing)? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41601137/972128

Comment: Disclaimer: this takes **20+ hours** on a low powered device like the Pi zero.

Comment: version `3.7` is [out](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370b3/)

Comment: I've did both altinstall and then make install but Python -V still shows 3.4.2 both times. Any idea @GAD3R?

Comment: `libffi-dev` is also required for Python 3.7. See https://bugs.python.org/issue31652 (make install fails: no module _ctypes)

Comment: FYI - a nicer way to do the build deps is to download the control file for the new version from a debian package, run: `mk-build-deps newPythonControlFile`, then install the generated package with something like `sudo gdebi python3.7-build-deps_1.0_amd64.deb`. Right now, it's the right-most link under "versioned links" here https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/python3.7 and named control-3.7.2-1 - though you might need to gently modify it (e.g. change the gcc version). You could do `mk-build-deps python3.5` instead, but it might not get all of them.

Comment: This actually ended up making this far worse for me. Likely going to have to reinstall Linux, as it killed python3, and after trying to reinstall it, `apt` is full of errors.

Comment: @Larnu you can revert back to the old python version through `sudo update-alternatives --config python`.

Comment: Please note that for Python 3.7 you need also `uuid-dev` on Debian

Comment: if U want to use this in a virtualenv don't use the `--with-ensurepip=install` option

Comment: I had to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43623903/5120089) too

Answer (score 37):

The official recommendation is "you don't actually need newer software"

[Don't suffer from Shiny New Stuff Syndrome - DontBreakDebian | Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_suffer_from_Shiny_New_Stuff_Syndrome)

Most of the advice on that page is geared towards what to do if you want the software to be available system-wide, but I don't think that's necessary in this case.

If you fetch the python sources, build the 3.6 interpreter using `--prefix` to control where it ends up, and then use `virtualenv` with the `--python` option, then you can use python 3.6 without affecting anything outside your project.

The process might go something like this:

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir pythonroot
$ mkdir opt
$ mkdir app
$ cd opt
$ wget <python tarball>
$ tar -xvf <python tarball>
$ cd python-3.6
$ ./configure --prefix="$HOME"/pythonroot
$ make
$ make install
$ cd ~
$ cd app
$ virtualenv venv --python ~/pythonroot/bin/python
$ . venv/bin/activate
[venv]$ which python
/home/<user>/pythonroot/bin/python
```

If you're going to do this, you may want to consider the [`--enable-optimizations` flag](https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/160) in the Python `configure` script, which seems to enable some features like profile-guided optimization. It increases build times but seems to result in a faster interpreter by 10% or so according to some benchmarks.

Comment: This follows general Python rule of "Practicality beats purity". I tend to install pythons from source packages in /opt/python-x.y.z and then run applications from its own virtualenvs.

Comment: Important note: if you're going to do something like this: make sure that whatever user your Python process runs as can't modify the virtualenv

Comment: In my opinion this is the best answer.

Comment: Thank for this advice. In the past I broke some debian install with system wide addon.

Comment: In my install `[venv]$ which python` do not give me `/home/<user>/pythonroot/bin/python`, but `/home/<user>/app/venv/bin/python3` instead… why?

Comment: @freezed ... I suspect that path might be a symlink. What does `realpath $(which python)` or `readlink -f $(which python)` if you do not have `realpath` give you?

Comment: `realpath $(which python)` : `/home/<user>/venv/bin/python3.6` Symlink but in same directory… Maybe I've set virtualenv option `--always-copy` to default somewhere? For real I used `--clear` in the command, this could be a clue.

Comment: @freezed ... I think you should make a separate question for this issue.

Answer (score 13):

You might want to have a look at `pyenv` : https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv . To quote from the `pyenv` tutorial at Amaral Lab:

> Previously known as Pythonbrew, pyenv lets you change the global
>   Python version, install multiple Python versions, set directory
>   (project)-specific Python versions, and yes create/manage virtual
>   python environments ("virtualenvs"). All this is done on *NIX-style
>   machines (Linux and OS X) without depending on Python itself and it
>   works at the user-level–no need for any sudo commands.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/173558)

Comment: You're right, will change the answer.

Comment: I think he meant to also include the essential command lines too...

Comment: This works well, except when you're dealing with embedded devices. To "install" a version of python, the source is downloaded and compiled locally. Other than that, pyenv is a great choice and has lots of flexibility, including running different python versions in different directories, and dealing with the very annoying PIP problems.

Comment: `pyenv` don't impress me much. Its official installation process is 'cat this script to shell', and the script uses git and clones untagged code, and then it builds the python from scratch (so it needs a compiler, too). ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 11):

My preferred way is to use [Anaconda](https://conda.io/docs/install/full.html#linux-anaconda-install) or [Miniconda](https://conda.io/docs/install/quick.html#linux-miniconda-install) to keep the latest version of python and packages installed on Debian.

It's all kept neatly in a folder which makes it very easy to remove later on if you wish. The installer also adds the path to your bashrc (add it yourself if you use another shell).

It comes with pip, and also conda which is another package manager than can be good for more complex pacakges like numpy. Miniconda is a bare bones install, and Anaconda is a full install with many packages, primarily designed for data analysis.

Quickly:

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Read and accept license, if you're not using bash add path: `export PATH="/home/$USER/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"`

Test:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.0 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

Install from PyPi:

```
# pip install fava
```

Install from conda:

```
# conda install numpy
```

When you want to delete it, remove the folder `~/miniconda3` and the path in your bashrc.

Comment: After endless problems with installing python from source, this version worked perfect! Note that if you want to work with virtualenv(wrapper) for the enviroment management, you need to add the miniconda library direcotry to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Eg: add `export $LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/miniconda3/lib"` to your `.bashrc`.

Comment: "The installer also adds the path to your bashrc" That is the primary reason why I do *not* use anaconda. Silently masking an existing python environment is not healthy, to say the least.

Answer (score 3):

Debian does not have Python 3.6 in it's repositories. Here's a snapshot of the current Python3 status:

```
wheezy (oldstable) (python): interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
    3.2.3-6: all
jessie (stable) (python): interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
    3.4.2-2: amd64 arm64 armel armhf i386 mips mipsel powerpc ppc64el s390x
stretch (testing) (python): interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
    3.5.1-4: amd64 arm64 armel armhf i386 mips mips64el mipsel ppc64el s390x
sid (unstable) (python): interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
    3.5.1-4: alpha amd64 arm64 armel armhf hppa hurd-i386 i386 kfreebsd-amd64 kfreebsd-i386 m68k mips mips64el mipsel powerpc powerpcspe ppc64 ppc64el s390x sh4 sparc64 x32
```

You can check these out [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python3).

You can install 3.6 either from source, or using something like Linuxbrew for a home directory installation.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.6 (though `rc1`) just arrived in Debian experimental. I was able to successfully build this on Debian stable (jessie). See the final steps of the build pasted below.

However, that doesn't mean it will install successfully and *not* cause problems. A reasonable next step would be to test it on a test VM of stable. If anyone cares, I could give it a try - or someone else could try.

A proper release version should arrive in Debian unstable shortly.

```
dh_builddeb -a
dpkg-deb: building package `python3.6' in `../python3.6_3.6.0~rc1-1_amd64.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package `python3.6-venv' in `../python3.6-venv_3.6.0~rc1-1_amd64.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package `libpython3.6-stdlib' in `../libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.0~rc1-1_amd64.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package `python3.6-minimal' in `../python3.6-minimal_3.6.0~rc1-1_amd64.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package `libpython3.6-minimal' in `../libpython3.6-minimal_3.6.0~rc1-1_amd64.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package `libpython3.6' in `../libpython3.6_3.6.0~rc1-1_amd64.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package `python3.6-dev' in `../python3.6-dev_3.6.0~rc1-1_amd64.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package `libpython3.6-dev' in `../libpython3.6-dev_3.6.0~rc1-1_amd64.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package `python3.6-dbg' in `../python3.6-dbg_3.6.0~rc1-1_amd64.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package `libpython3.6-dbg' in `../libpython3.6-dbg_3.6.0~rc1-1_amd64.deb'.
 dpkg-genchanges  >../python3.6_3.6.0~rc1-1_amd64.changes
dpkg-genchanges: including full source code in upload
 dpkg-source --after-build python3.6-3.6.0~rc1
dpkg-buildpackage: full upload (original source is included)
Now running lintian...
W: python3.6 source: newer-standards-version 3.9.8 (current is 3.9.6)
N: 56 tags overridden (26 errors, 27 warnings, 3 info)
Finished running lintian.
```

Answer (score 2):

With this

```
sudo echo "http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian testing main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python3.6
```

Successfully work.

More : set python3.6 as default

```
sudo alias python=/usr/bin/python3.6
```

Right now :

```
python --version
Python 3.6
```

Comment: Should read `sudo echo "deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian testing main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: This answer is the same as the accepted answer, came one year later, and yet fails at giving correct commands.

Comment: There is `python3.7` now in the `testing`

Answer (score 0):

As of September 2019, the latest debian stable (buster) has python 3.7. So the proper and officially accepted procedure would now be to [upgrade to debian buster](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html).

Comment: "To upgrade python, first upgrade the world".This, whilst one way to do it, does not solve one's immediate problem.

Comment: GAD3R's answer very well covers how to install a later version of python without bricking your system like the accepted answer does. Upgrading the whole system is the only other alternative that comes to mind; it's a very different approach.

Comment: Interestingly the answer that “bricks your system” doesn’t seem to currently even let you do that, possibly due to repo changes as a result of Jessie going into the archive. But, having to install the compiler and developer libs is not always the path one wants to go down either.