# How do I undo the steps I've taken to turn my installation into "FrankenDebian"?

Tags: debian, apt, raspbian, repository

I was looking to install Python 3.6 on my Raspberry Pi (which is running Raspian jessie), and I followed the instructions in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340482/291433) without reading the warning below. First of all, python3.6 didn't even install, and second of all, the `apt-get install` I tried doing afterwards failed. My understanding is that my installation is now at risk of being broken (i.e. becoming a [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian)) due to mixing non-stable repositories.

How can I undo what I have done? The only commands of relevance that I've executed are

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
# add
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian testing main
$ echo 'APT::Default-Release "stable";' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00local
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get -t testing install python3.6
$ python3.6 -V
```

When I try to `apt-get install` anything, I get the error:

```
E: The value 'stable' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message you’re getting,

```
E: The value 'stable' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources.
```

isn’t directly related to the addition of testing; it’s caused by the `APT::Default-Release "stable"` setting (I’m guessing your `sources.list` references “jessie” rather than “stable”). To fix that, remove the corresponding line from `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00local`.

To undo the other operations, and return to a non-FrankenDebian using Jessie only:

- remove the `testing` line from `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- update the indexes:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  ```
- downgrade any package which was upgraded back to the version in Debian 9:

  ```
  sudo apt install $(printf "%s/stable " $(apt list --installed | grep -v /stable | cut -d/ -f1))
  ```

The latter command will list all installed packages, find any which are not installed in a version available in Raspbian Jessie (by excluding anything listed as `/stable`), extract the package names, reformat them with `/stable` appended, and instruct `apt` to install them, which will re-install the packages in their Raspbian Jessie version.

Comment: The error was `E: The value 'stable' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources`. I'll try your answer and report back.

Comment: The third command you suggested yielded the same error above.