# debian 8 (jessie) - virtualenv with python3.6

Tags: debian, python, python3, virtualenv

so i have a fresh debian install. I installed pythons 3.5,3.6,3.7:

```
root@m2:~# apt-get install python3.{5,6,7}-dev
```

and try to set up some virtualenvs:

```
for i in 5 6 7 ; do dir=venv3.$i; echo $dir; mkdir $dir; virtualenv $dir --python=python3.$i; done
```

result:

```
-------------
venv3.5
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.5
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /root/venv3.5/bin/python3.5
Also creating executable in /root/venv3.5/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
-------------
venv3.6
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 25, in <module>
    import distutils.spawn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.spawn'
-------------
venv3.7
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.7
Using base prefix '/usr'
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py:1047: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
New python executable in /root/venv3.7/bin/python3.7
Also creating executable in /root/venv3.7/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

any idea how to fix this for python 3.6?

the exact version is:

```
root@m2:~# dpkg-query -s python3.6
Package: python3.6
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: python
Installed-Size: 326
Maintainer: Matthias Klose <doko@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: allowed
Version: 3.6.8-1
```

Meanwhile, on some older system I also have debian 8 and python3.6, and there it works ok:

```
root@m1:~# dpkg-query -s python3.6
Package: python3.6
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: python
Installed-Size: 315
Maintainer: Matthias Klose <doko@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: allowed
Version: 3.6.6-4

root@m1:~# virtualenv venv3.6 --python=python3.6
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /root/venv3.6/bin/python3.6
Also creating executable in /root/venv3.6/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
```

Comment: Any specific reason you are creating three virtual env's at once?

Comment: Well I just need the one with py36. But I wasnt able to do it, I wanted to check what's wrong. Now I presume, that this is some problem with python3.6 from debian repo

Comment: Well, the issue is present in upstream, I was having similar issues creating a virtualenv. The upstream codebase for virtualenv is having bugs which might have got carried in Debian repos. Take a look at https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2871

Comment: I filed a bug under debian: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918881

Comment: A work-around may be to find out where the `distutils` package is supposed to be for Python 3.6, e.g. by running `python3.6 -c 'import distutils; print(distutils.__file__)'` and replace its contents with the files used by Python 3.7 (which appears to be working in your case).

Comment: Yeah, i kind of do similar. I install package python3-distutils from python3.7 (deb file directly by dpkg) and it kind of works. Debian removed python3.6 completely from their repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on *Debian testing/buster* : since `python3` is targeting `python3.7`, starting a new virtual environment with `python3.6` provided by *Debian-apt* fails (when `2.7`, `3.5` & `3.7` succeeded) :

```
$ virtualenv --clear --python=python3.6 .venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 25, in <module>
   import distutils.sysconfig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.sysconfig'
zsh: exit 1     virtualenv --clear --python=python3.6 .venv
```

I look around and it looks like *Debian's fault*.
I am not able to fix it, then I removed *Debian's 3.6 flavor* and I installed `python3.6` from source in *user-land* (following [this post's step](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350985/280824)).

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir pythonroot
$ mkdir opt
$ mkdir app
$ cd opt
$ wget Python-3.6.8.tgz
$ tar -xvzf Python-3.6.8.tgz 
$ cd Python-3.6.8
$ ./configure --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install --prefix="$HOME"/pythonroot
$ make
$ make install
$ cd ~/app
$ virtualenv --python ~/pythonroot/bin/python3.6 .venv
$ source .venv/bin/activate
(.venv)$ python -V
Python 3.6.8
```